# Oracle Selenium integration testing

Tags: java, oracle, selenium, webdriver

As part of integration testing, I would like to test some integrations between a web application and its data store (Oracle DB).

There is a table I would like to check the values stored within. I am trying to think of the best way to achieve this.

My Selenium Web Driver tests are data-driven from a spreadsheet. Would I prepare some queries and just compare the data in the DB with the data that exists in the spreadsheet, or is it best to output the data in the DB to an object array and then compare with the data from the spreadsheet?

Thanks

Comment: This is quite an inefficient way of working: don't you have service-level integration tests? If you have to compare the raw DB output against the user-displayed values that suggests at least one or two layers of (much faster) tests are missing.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say if you're wanting to test the integration pulling something from the database, you're better checking it in the webapp or as close to the webapp as you can get.

If you mean the webapp is setting some values in the database and you want to check that those are properly set, I don't see any reason not to directly check the DB tables against your expected values.